# Voice recognition gives out Type error NoneType none iterable

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I have a password recognition code that goes like this:

```
from wit import Wit
import pyttsx3, time

def speak(string):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty('rate', 220)

    engine.say(string)
    engine.runAndWait()

def Hear():
    recog = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio= recog.listen(source)
        print (audio)
        return 

    wit_key = 'FO7EYTKK6OHRSZ3A5UFPMZOC7VIXCVSY'
    try:
        print('VEXD THINKS YOU SAID '+ recog.recognize_wit(audio, key=wit_key))
        heard = recog.recognize_wit(audio, key=wit_key)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("I DIDN't get that")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("SERVER DISCONECTED")

speak("CHECKING IDENTITY" )
sound = Hear()
time.sleep(1)
if "master"in sound:
    speak("Yes My Lord")
```

It is supposed to say YEs my lord when I say master
but when I say master , it returns this error

```
File "c:/Users/tdmfa/OneDrive/Desktop/VEXD app/VEXD AI/AI_START.py", line 33, in <module>
    if "master"in sound:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Line `if "master"in sound:` tries to iterate through `sound` and the error say that objects of `NoneType` are not iterable. The expanation is obvious: `sound` is an object of type `NoneType`, i.e. `sound` is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sound= Hear()
```

This line of code, doesn't receive any output from the `Hear()` function. Your `Hear()` function doesn't return any value, it simply exits the function and returns `None`. That is why it says 
`'NoneType' is not iterable`, because you are trying to iterate over `sound`.

This should work:

```
from wit import Wit
import pyttsx3, time
import speech_recognition as sr


def speak(string):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty('rate', 220)

    engine.say(string)
    engine.runAndWait()

def Hear():
    recog= sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio= recog.listen(source)
        

    wit_key = 'FO7EYTKK6OHRSZ3A5UFPMZOC7VIXCVSY'
    try:
        audio_str = recog.recognize_wit(audio, key=wit_key)
        print('VEXD THINKS YOU SAID '+ audio_str)
        return audio_str
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        error1 = "I DIDN't get that"
        print(error1)
        return error1
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        error2 = "SERVER DISCONNECTED"
        print(error2)
        return error2

speak("CHECKING IDENTITY")
sound= Hear()
time.sleep(1)
if "master" in sound:
    speak("Yes My Lord")
```

Comment: So what sould I do I am kind of new to python

Comment: You would have to return the output from a variable in the function. I am not very familiar with this library, so I would have to read the documentation.

Comment: @VLCTYViper I added code. It should work, but comment if it doesn't

Comment: That's great to hear! If my answer worked, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be returning `heard` from your `Hear()` function, instead of `None` as it currently does. There are two exit points in that function, both return `None`:

- the call to `return` right after audio is obtained by the recogniser
- implicitly when the function ends without calling `return` to return a specific value.

To fix, remove the `return` call just after the recogniser gets the audio, and then add `return heard` after `heard = recog.recognize_wit(audio, key=wit_key)`. The function can still return `None` if one of the expected exceptions is raised, so you will want to probably want to return an empty list, or retry as appropriate.

I am not familiar with the libraries that you are using, so I am assuming that `heard` will be some kind of iterable (list, tuple, string, etc.) that makes sense to the rest of your code.